# How to separate head?

Tags: jsf, templating, jspx

Here how look my .jspx files:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.1" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
          xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
     <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="true"  doctype-root-element="HTML" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/html5"/>
    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
    <f:loadBundle basename="my.pack.resource" var="r"/>
    <f:loadBundle basename="my.pack.error" var="e"/>
    <f:view>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html utf-8"/>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
            <title> Some title </title>
            <jsp:directive.include file="/temp/myLayout.jspf" />            
        </head>


        <body>

            <h:form>            

                <h:commandLink .........

                </h:form>

        </body>


        </html>
    </f:view>
</jsp:root>
```

In order to keep my view files clear and small 
I would like to put all **above  and after body** in 
templates and include it in my .ispx files and pass title as parameter.

If anybody knows solution, please help.

**EDIT**
I have changed my view from .jspx to .xhtml, but my servlet filters now don't work.
Here my web.xml:

```
   <?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'windows-1252'?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_VIEW_MAPPINGS</param-name>
        <param-value>*.xhtml;*.jsf</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>loginFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>my.pack.filterpack.LoginFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>remebermefilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>my.pack.filterpack.RemeberMeFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>NoCacheFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>my.pack.filterpack.NoCacheFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>loginFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/view/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>remebermefilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/login/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>NoCacheFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>                
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>


    <!-- servlet mappings -->

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/index.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
        <location>/viewExp.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>my.pack.timer.MyJobManager</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the reasons why JSP(X) is abandoned, deprecated and succeeded by Facelets 4 years ago. JSP(X) doesn't offer easy templating capabilities in order to achieve this kind of requirements.

Just migrate to Facelets. Rename `.jspx` to `.xhtml` and replace `<jsp:xxx>` tags by `<ui:xxx>` tags. Your functional requirement is answered in 2nd example of [How to include another XHTML in XHTML using JSF 2.0 Facelets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792862/how-to-include-another-xhtml-in-xhtml-using-jsf-2-0-facelets/4793959#4793959)

Facelets is natively available in JSF 2.x. If you're still using JSF 1.x, then you can just install it separately as per [its documentation](https://facelets.java.net/nonav/docs/dev/docbook.html).

Comment: BalusC thank you for help.I have changed my view files to .xhtml, but now my servlet filters don't work. Can you help?

Comment: Alter their mappings accordingly.

Comment: Get rid of all `<dispatcher>FORWARD` entries. It defaults to the right one, `REQUEST` already. On contrary to JSP(X), Facelets doesn't use the old fashioned dispatcher anymore to locate the view.

Comment: Thanks balusC, it helped me, but now in my RemeberMeFilter FacesContext.getCurrentInstance() is null.

Comment: That's a different problem. You're not supposed to use JSF artifacts in servlet filters anyway. For example, if you intend to use `FacesContext` to grab a session scoped managed bean, just get it from the `HttpSession` directly.